# Cancel background worker which is calling external process

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have created a TelNet server for a project I need to do which is working fine, however when a client connects to the server it needs to connect to a database, again this works fine when the connection information is correct and/or calls to the database do not take too long.

If the database call takes a long time (usually due to incorrect credentials or a badly optimised stored procedure) the server will crash with a Windows error message (i.e. not debuggable), which I understand is the underlying TCP system kicking in, which is fine. To resolve this I am putting all the database calls into `BackgroundWorkers`, so the server (and clients) continue to work, however I need to kill off this process if it is obviously taking too long.

I know about using `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending`, but as this is a single method call to the database (via and external DLL), it will never get checked. Same issue with a self-made approach that I have seen elsewhere. The other option I have seen is using `Thread.Abort()`, but I also know that is unpredictable and unsafe, so probably best not to use that.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that an external DLL is controlling the waiting. Normally, you could cancel ADO.NET connections or socket connections but this doesn't work here.

Two reliable approaches:

- Move the connection into a child process that you can kill. Kill is safe (in contrast to Thread.Abort!) because *all* state of that process is gone at the same time.
- Structure the application so that in case of cancellation the result of the connection attempt is just being ignored and that the app continues running something else. You just let the hanging connection attempt "dangle" in the background and throw away its result when it happens to return later.